# Differential Equations: solve the system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following system:

$$dx/dt=-.2(y-2)$$ $$dy/dt=.8(x-2)$$

This is what I have so far, but I got stuck..
$$\begin{eqnarray}
dx/dt&=&-.2y-.4\\
x'&=&-.2y-.4\\
x'+.4&=&-.2y\\
y&=&-x/2'-2\\
y&=&-x''/2-2\\
\\
dy/dt&=&.8(x-2)\\
dy/dt&=&.8x-1.6\\
y'&=&.8x-1.6\\
-x''-2&=&.8x-1.6\\
-x''&=&.8x+.4\\
x''+16x+.8&=&0
\end{eqnarray}$$
 when I used the quadratic formula I got stuck. Is this correct so far? Can someone finish it off for me?

Comment: First step: $x(t)=u(t)+2$, $y(t)=v(t)+2$, yields $u'(t)=-av(t)$, $v'(t)=bu(t)$ with $a=.2$, $b=.8$. Second step: $u''(t)=-av'(t)=-\omega^2u(t)$ with $\omega^2=ab$. Third step: $u(t)=A\cos(\omega t+\theta)$. Fourth step: $v(t)=-u'(t)/a$ hence $v(t)=B\sin(\omega t+\theta)$ with $B=A\omega/a=2A$. Final step: $x(t)=A\cos(\omega t+\theta)+2$ and $y(t)=2A\sin(\omega t+\theta)+2$.

Comment: 106 questions, people asking you to learn MathJax, and still not using it?

Comment: I edited this just enough to make it possible to read it without a headache. In so doing, a couple of minor errors (missing or misplaced $'$ marks) came to light. I did not fix those; OP may wish to do so.

Answer (score 0):

With $X=(x-2)$ and $Y=(y-2)$

$\frac{dX}{dt}=aY$ where $a=-0.2$

$\frac{dY}{dt}=bX$ where $b=0.8$ $$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{bX}{aY}$$ $$2YdY=\frac{b}{a}2XdX$$ $$Y^2=\frac{b}{a}X^2+constant$$ $$Y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}X^2+c_1}$$ $\frac{dX}{dt}=\pm a \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}X^2+c_1}$ $$dt=\frac{dX}{\pm a\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}X^2+c_1}}$$ I suppose thant you can continue : integrate, without forgeting $c_2$, which leads to an arcsin function of $t$ because $\frac{b}{a}<0$. Then express $X(t)$ as a sin function. Then bring it into $Y^2=\frac{b}{a}X^2+c_1$ in order to obtain $Y(t)$. Finally, $y(t)=Y(t)+2$ and $x(t)=X(t)+2$

Comment: Your equations will be simplified if you change of variables $X=(x-2)$ and $Y=(y-2)$. Another method is shown in my answer below.

Comment: Really the hard way, don't you think?

Comment: @Did: The hard way, sure ! For pleasure, it was an opportunity to mention the method of elimination of $dt$, which is very useful in many cases (but not always, of course).